# Blue screen of death while unlocking computer with Visual Studio 2010 running

Tags: bsod, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed along with DevExpress 10.2. When I lock the machine and unlock it, a blue screen of death appears.

I also experience the same problem when the machine is kept running for about one to two hours.  The same software is installed on a desktop, but no problem there.

My laptop is a Dell Latitude E6410.

Comment: While you are referring to software development tools, this does not feel like a *programming related* question. Voting to move to superuser.com.

Comment: Are you running on Windows 7 x64? Because I do and Visual Studio 2010 doesn't like my GPU drivers and keeps black-screening me... :(

Comment: *> While you are referring to software development tools, this does not feel like a programming related question.*   It’s not even a programming-*tools* related question since it apparently happens when the system is simply kept running for a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Solution/workaround for Dell Latitude E6410:

Upgrade the graphics driver XP32 Intel GMA HD Integrated Graphics Driver (Intel_multi-device_A05_R296698). The crash issue while locking and unlocking doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Read some articles about finding root cause of BSOD, here are few:

- [HOW TO: Debug Memory Dumps (Figure out what is causing a BSOD)](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?p=1418737)
- [How to debug a (BSOD) Blue Screen of Death – Part 1](http://www.asktheadmin.com/2007/09/how-to-debug-bsod-blue-screen-of-death.html)
- [How to debug a Blue Screen of Death (BSOD)- Part 2](http://www.asktheadmin.com/2007/09/how-to-debug-a-blue-screen-of-death-bsod-part-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same problem on a Lenovo T410 (running xp 32bit). If I come out of vs2010 before locking the screen it does. Turning off hardware acceleration for WPF seems to have helped

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx#disablehardwareacceleration

Your milage may vary though.

Answer (score 0):

Any kernel mode exception (Blue Screen of Death) is caused by code running in mode.

And it's almost *certainly* not caused by Microsoft's own kernel code, but by a 3rd party driver that is also running in kernel mode.

The symptoms here suggest that the BSOD is almost certainly caused by a *video card driver*. I.e. a video mode switch, with 3D application (WPF) running. Your video card's driver wasn't expecting that, and it caused it to execute invalid code.

---

At the very ***least***, you need to provide the stop error code, e.g.:

```
Stop: 0x00000050  (PAGE_FAULT_IN_NON_PAGED_AREA)
```

and the parameters that accompany the error code, e.g. in the case of `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NON_PAGED_AREA`:

```
0x8872A990: The memory addressed referenced
0x00000001: 0=Read, 1=Write
0x804F35D7: The address that referenced the memory
0x00000000: (reserved)
```

for whatever your stop error is, e.g.:

[image]

Other than that:

- update your video card's drivers; hopefully they fixed the bug
- update your video card; if they didn't fix the bug then certainly another manufacturer won't have the bug
- ask the video card to do less *video-card stuff* e.g.

  - turn off WPF (3D video card stuff)
  - turn off video card acceleration (video card stuff)
  - lower the resolution (video card stuff)